# Closing system alert through ADB Android

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to automate system alert closing through adb.
I am using some external camera hardware connected to target Android device.
When the camera gets connected, the following prompt appears:

```
Main App

Open Main App to handle Camera ?

Always open Main App to handle when Camera is connected

CANCEL / OK
```

I would like to close the prompt without having to use the screen.
Is it possible to do so using adb shell or bash script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try the following:

1. use [UI Automator Viewer](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator#ui-automator-viewer), navigate into the layout tree and get the `resource-id` corresponding to the cancel button.
2. install the [AndroidViewClient library](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)
3. use the following python script to automatically click the cancel button from the bash

> ```
> #! /usr/bin/env python
>
> import sys
> import os
>
> try:
>     sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
> except:
>     pass
>
> from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
>
> vc = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit())
>
> #replace your-resource-id with the cancel button resource id
> view = vc.findViewById("your-resource-id")
> if view:
>     print view.__tinyStr__()
>     view.touch()
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does the job perfectly.